# libreoffice tab behind end margin

Tags: libreoffice

In the feature list of Libreoffice 3.5 I read, that it is possible to set an tabulator behind the end margin ([1] text from feature list), so the text will continue after this tab instead inserting a newline.
I've tried this with Libreoffice 3.5.4, but it seems not to work.

Any suggestions, what i did wrong?
Or did I misunderstood this feature?

Cheers Sven

[1]
When a tab stop is set behind the end margin, the tab uses this value and does not go to a new line. A compatibility option has been added, thus only new documents will behave this way.